# react-admin not working if it is in other component and not app.js

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-admin

I'm trying to integrate `React-Admin` `AdminDashboard` component into a larger React application that uses React-Router for navigation. However, I'm encountering issues where `AdminDashboard` doesn't render or work as expected.

When I initially had the `AdminDashboard` directly in `App.js`, everything functioned correctly, and the URL displayed as `"http://localhost:3000/AdminDashboard/#/users"`. However, after refactoring `AdminDashboard` into a separate component, the page fails to load, and the URL changes unexpectedly to `"http://localhost:3000/users"` or `"http://localhost:3000/posts"` as comes first in Resources.

This issue began only after moving the `AdminDashboard` code into its own component, indicating a potential problem with how the routing or component integration is handled.

I first made the app like [Blog.logrocket](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-create-react-admin-panel)

Before refactoring `AdminDashboard.jsx` wasn't a separate component and it was inside app.js like the code down below:

```
//here all the imports
const app = () => {
  return (
    <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider}>
      <Resource name="posts" list={PostList} />
      <Resource name="users" list={UserList} />
    </Admin>
  );
};
// exporting the app, and all this was working fine
```

Below is my latest code setup and its not working:

AdminDashboard.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Admin, Resource } from 'react-admin';
import UserList from './User';
import PostList from './Posts';
import restProvider from 'ra-data-simple-rest';

const dataProvider = restProvider('http://localhost:3000');

const AdminDashboard = () => {
  return (
    <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider}>
      <Resource name="posts" list={PostList} />
      <Resource name="users" list={UserList} />
    </Admin>
  );
};

export default AdminDashboard;
```

App.js:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from "./components/Layout/Header";
import Footer from "./components/Layout/Footer";
import Homepage from "./components/Homepage";
import NotFound from "./components/Layout/NotFound";
import PrivateRoute from "./components/Routing/PrivateRoute";
import Login from "./components/Admin/Login";
import AdminDashboard from "./components/Admin/AdminDashboard";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<LayoutsWithHeader />}>
            <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
            <Route exact path="/" element={<Homepage />} />
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
            <Route element={<PrivateRoute />}>
              <Route path="/AdminDashboard/*" element={<AdminDashboard />} />
            </Route>
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

const LayoutsWithHeader = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Outlet />
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

range.js

```js
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Content-Range", "users 0-20/20");
  res.header("Content-Range", "Posts 0-20/20");
  next();
};
```

My latest code structure :

```
appname/
├── client/                              # Client-side React application
│   ├── public/                          # Static files
│   ├── src/
│   │   ├── components/
│   │   │   ├── Admin/
│   │   │   │   ├── AdminDashboard.jsx   # Admin dashboard component
│   │   │   │   ├── Login.jsx            # Login component
│   │   │   │   ├── Posts.jsx            # Posts component
│   │   │   │   └── Users.jsx            # Users component
│   │   │   ├── Layout/
│   │   │   │   ├── Footer.jsx           # Footer layout component
│   │   │   │   ├── Header.jsx           # Header layout component
│   │   │   │   └── NotFound.jsx         # Not found component
│   │   │   ├── Routing/
│   │   │   │   └── PrivateRoute.jsx     # Private route component
│   │   │   └── Homepage.jsx             # Homepage component
│   │   ├── App.css                      # Main CSS file for the app
│   │   ├── App.js                       # Main JavaScript file for React app
│   │   ├── App.test.js                  # Test file for the app
│   │   ├── index.css                    # CSS file for index component
│   │   ├── index.js                     # Entry point for React app
│   │   ├── logo.svg                     # Logo file
│   │   ├── reportWebVitals.js           # Web vitals report utility
│   │   └── setupTests.js                # Setup file for tests
│   ├── package.json                     # NPM package file for the client
│   └── node_modules/                    # Node modules for the client
│
├── server/                              # Server-side Node.js application
│   ├── Controllers/                     # Controllers for server logic
│   ├── middlewares/                     # Middlewares for the server
│   ├── Models/                          # Data models for the server
│   ├── Routers/                         # Route definitions for the server
│   ├── config/
│   │   └── config.env                   # Environment config file
│   ├── node_modules/                    # Node modules for the server
│   ├── uploads/                         # Uploaded files directory
│   ├── package-lock.json                # NPM lock file for server
│   ├── package.json                     # NPM package file for the server
│   ├── range.js                         # Additional JavaScript file
│   ├── server.js                        # Entry point for Node.js server
│   └── db.json                          # Mock database JSON file
│
├── .gitignore                           # Git ignore file
├── links.json                           # Additional JSON file
├── package-lock.json                    # NPM lock file for root
├── package.json                         # NPM package file for root
├── README.md                            # Readme file for the project
└── request.log                          # Log file for server requests
```

I've examined the routing setup, and while I initially believed it wasn't the issue, I'm starting to suspect it might be related to the problem after all, given my current understanding.

Extra code and info:

the link in header:

```
  <Link to="/AdminDashboard">
    AdminDashboard
  </Link>
</>
```

Part of client-side package.json:

```json
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
"dependencies": {
  "react": "^18.2.0",
  "react-admin": "^4.16.4",
  "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
```

Part of servier-side package.json:

```json
"scripts": {
  "server": "json-server --watch db.json --port 5000 --middlewares ./range.js",
  "client": "npm start --prefix ./client",
  "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the `<Admin basename>` prop as explained in the [Using React-Admin in a route](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html#using-react-admin-inside-a-route) section?

By this way, react-admin will include the `basename` in all links.

Something like:

```
const AdminDashboard = () => (
  <Admin basename="/AdminDashboard">
    // ... 
  </Admin>
);

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div className="App">
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/">
                        // ...
                        <Route
                            path="/AdminDashboard/*"
                            element={<AdminDashboard />}
                        />
                    </Route>
                </Routes>
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

With a URL like `"http://localhost:3000/AdminDashboard/#/users"` implies you were previously using hash routing. The app was served/hosted from `"http://localhost:3000/AdminDashboard/#"` and the accessible routes were:

- `"/"` root/home page
- `"/users"` users page
- `"/posts"` posts page

You then added client-side routing, e.g. `react-router-dom` and use a `BrowserRouter`. It seems the `BrowserRouter` thinks it is running from `"http://localhost:3000"`, so the same routes above work relative to *this*. I suspect you could just add a [`basename`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/browser-router#basename) prop to the router and edit the "admin dashboard" to omit the path prefix. This configures the router to run under a specific basename in the URL.

Example:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
...

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router basename="/AdminDashboard">
      <div className="App">
        <Routes>
          <Route element={<LayoutsWithHeader />}>
            <Route path="/" element={<Homepage />} />
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
            <Route element={<PrivateRoute />}>
              <Route path="/*" element={<AdminDashboard />} />
            </Route>
            <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you it worked 80% the last thing  came to
`<Router basename="/">`

Comment: @husamsaleh Interesting, it should work the say way 100% of the time, right or wrong. `"/"` is the default value, all routes and links are relative from `"/"` by default. Changing the `basename` prop allows for them to be relative from the sub-directory where the app/router is running. Have you tried switching back to a `HashRouter`?